# CS code change not applied after importing a solution from another machine

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2017

I have imported a web project from another machine.  Then I built it and ran it on my machine. I changed my `.aspx` file and the change applied successfully. But when I changed the `CodeBehind`, `.aspx.cs` file the change is not applied.

I have tried:

1. Restarting VS and restarting machine. (not working)
2. Saving all and building again. (not working)
3. Delete the bin folder's contents. (not successful)

After I deleted the project dll file my code threw exceptions.

After I cleaned the `bin` folder I can't build it again and it throws errors.

Comment: Are you running VS in administrative mode?, If not try that too

Comment: Have you checked .net framework and other required configurations.

Comment: Sometimes problems comes with web config file too. Make sure any changes happend in web config.

Comment: @Bosco, run as administrative but no luck.

Comment: @Md.SukelAli What error is thrown exactly?

Comment: @dpant Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error: `Could not load type 'ERPSSL.Global'. E:\Code\ERP\fresh\27072019\ERPSSL\Global.asax`

Comment: @Md.SukelAli Are you sure the project is of the same type in both machines? This error message appears in cases a Web Site project is converted to a Web Application project.